# Keep Jenkins child process running after build completes

Tags: python, jenkins, npm

I am trying to figure out how to keep a process running after the Jenkins build completes.

I have a build step that is suppose to close the current node.exe process and start it again by calling "npm start". This is the contents of restart_node.bat

```
Taskkill /IM node.exe /F
cd C:\node
call npm start
```

I can see that is successfully stops and starts a new process, but as soon as the build completes.. the node.exe process gets killed. How can I leave it running after the build?

[image]

Comment: Search for "[jenkins] background process" or "[jenkins] long running process" or "[jenkins] detached process"; lots of Q & A.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set an environment variable named BUILD_ID to some value of your choosing, and, Jenkins should become aware of your desire to "not kill" the child.

   - In case of Jenkins Pipeline use JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE instead of BUILD_ID
2. You may wish to use "sh" (bash, for instance) instead of "Windows Batch command", or, you may need to further discover more details about how "cmd.exe" handles killing  (or not) of its child processes.

References:

- https://stbtestautomation.wordpress.com/2016/08/02/jenkins-dont-quit-child-process-when-build-finished/

  - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am a bit new to Jenkins.. where do I set up the environment variable "BUILD_ID" and how?

Comment: This is the correct answer.

If you're using pipeline script, you need set JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE instead of BUILD_ID

pipeline {
  environment {
    JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE = "STAYINALIVE"
  }
...
}